# Header and Footer are not coming in Prestashop FrontEnd Module

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop not able to get Header and Footer in the Custom Module Created for the FrontOffice

Also not able to add the theme.css file with the way $this->context->controller->addCSS('path');

Main Module File testmodule.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
   exit;


/* @var boolean error */
protected $_errors = false;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'testmodule';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0';
    $this->author = 'Nemo';
    $this->need_instance = 0;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('testmodule');
    $this->description = $this->l('Adds a block.');
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to delete this module?');
    //$this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'testmodule/css/testmodule.css', 'all');
}

public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
  $this->context->controller->addCSS('\themes\PRS01\assets\css\theme.css','all');       
  $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/testmodule.css', 'all');
}


public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $this->addCSS('\themes\PRS01\assets\css\theme.css');
        $this->setTemplate('allproducts.tpl');  
}   

public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() &&
!$this->registerHook('header'))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function uninstall()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall())
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function countAllProducts()
{
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT COUNT(*) from ps_product WHERE active = 1');
}
}
```

Controller File:

```
<?php

Class testmoduleAllproductsModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{


    public function init(){

        $this->page_name = 'allproducts';
        //$this->display_column_left = false;
        parent::init();

    }



    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();

        $this->context->controller->addCSS('\themes\PRS01\assets\css\theme.css', 'all');

    } 

    public function initContent(){
     //   parent::initContent();
     //  echo "hello";

    // $this->setTemplate('allproducts.tpl');   


            //$this->context->controller->addCSS('/js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css');
             parent::initContent();

            $products_partial = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, 5, 'name', 'asc');
            $products = Product::getProductsProperties($this->context->language->id, $products_partial);

            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'products' => $products,
                'homeSize' => Image::getSize('home_default'),
                'HOOK_HEADER' => Hook::exec('displayHeader')
            ));
            //$this->setTemplate('allproducts.tpl');
          //  setMedia();


            $this->context->controller->addCSS('\themes\PRS01\assets\css\theme.css');
            //$this->addCSS('themes\PRS01\assets\css\theme.css');
             $this->setTemplate('module:testmodule/views/templates/front/allproducts.tpl');
            $this->addCSS('module:testmodule/css/testmodule.css');
            //return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/front/allproducts.tpl');


    } 

}
```

.tpl file to show the module

```
 <h1> Hello World </h1>
```

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: In your Frontend Module template (.tpl) file write {extends file='page.tpl'} It will give your theme Header, Footer and custom page layout. This is the solution for Prestashop 1.7. 
Kindly look any one the existing Front-end module template file like, themes\classic\templates\customer\my-account.tpl, and look out their implementation, they did the same.

Comment: Thanks @Honey Thakuria

Comment: Kindly upvote the question If you feel that it was relevant :)

Answer (score 3):

You should try to extends your tpl file as page, you can change tpl file content like this then it's display header and footer too.

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name='page_content'}
    Your Codes
{/block}
```